# Using IntelliJ Plugin SDK to add a custom new module template (Android Studio)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When AndroidStudio stopped supporting project template files they switched to the plugin architecture.  I'm new to IntelliJ plugins and want to recreate the templates i've lost.

I'm trying to use the plugin to create a "New Module" template.  Basically, the idea is the user will right click on an app project, and select "New Common Module" and a new module will appear in the project with all my custom gradle files etc.

I'm having trouble even creating the module in the first place. Here is the "Recipe" for the plugin.

```
fun RecipeExecutor.MyModuleSetup(
        moduleData: ModuleTemplateData,
        packageName: String,
        entityName: String,
        moduleName: String,
) {
    val (projectData) = moduleData
    val project = projectInstance ?: return
    addAllKotlinDependencies(moduleData)
    try {
        WriteCommandAction.writeCommandAction(project).compute(ThrowableComputable<Module, RuntimeException> {
            val f: VirtualFile = createProjectSubFile(ModuleManager.getInstance(project).modules[0]).contentRoots[0].path, "$moduleName/$moduleName.iml")
            val module = ModuleManager.getInstance(project).newModule(f.path, ModuleTypeId.JAVA_MODULE)
            PsiTestUtil.addContentRoot(module, f.parent)
            module
        })
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun createProjectSubFile(projectPath: String?, relativePath: String?): VirtualFile {
    val f = File(projectPath, relativePath)
    FileUtil.ensureExists(f.getParentFile())
    FileUtil.ensureCanCreateFile(f)
    val created: Boolean = f.createNewFile()
    if (!created && !f.exists()) {
        throw AssertionError("Unable to create the project sub file: " + f.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    return LocalFileSystem.getInstance().refreshAndFindFileByIoFile(f)!!
}
```

If I use the plugin to create a new module named "mod1" in a project called "app1", what I'm hoping is for a new director like this:

/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/tests/app1/mod1

Instead, nothing happens!  Am I supposed to write something out before it shows up?

Is this the right approach on how to create a new module in a project with the plugin?

Thanks folks!